# webauthn example indicates browser is not supported when cross compiled but works on host machine

Tags: javascript, go, webauthn

I am testing a very simple webauthn example written with go from https://github.com/hbolimovsky/webauthn-example and it works very well when I build it  for the host machine. I am using MacOS Big Sur with Chrome 91. However, if I build the example for an arm7/linux machine, I am getting "browser not supported" error message.

Clearly the browser is supported since it works on the host machine. The code that checks for browser support is this

```
// check whether current browser supports WebAuthn
if (!window.PublicKeyCredential) {
     alert("Error: this browser does not support WebAuthn");
     return;
   }
```

The cross compiled machine doesn't have internet access though I am highly doubtful that that is the reason. What can be the reason for this?

I am accessing the cross compiled machine through it's IP address. Can that be the reason? To test this I accessed it through it's bonjour name and that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you access your linux/arm machine with your browser? WebAuthn only works in a secure context, http://localhost or https://anywhereelse that is...

Comment: Thank you. That might be the reason. The simple example is a server on http. I will try to set up https.

Comment: I've filed a pull request in the original code to help detect that situation https://github.com/hbolimovsky/webauthn-example/pull/3

Comment: Sure enough, that was the reason. I passed the warning but I cannot register a user. Are there any other limitations regarding certificate? I am using self signed root certificate with RSA

Comment: I tried elliptic curve but that didn't make a difference

Comment: Seems like webauthn doesn't like self signed certificate with IP address as the CN name.